# Non-Stationary Data with Lagged Dependent Variable?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, stationarity, spurious-correlation

I am currently dealing with non-stationary data and I am unsure of how to proceed. My data is stationary in first differences I(1), which I confirmed using a Dickey-Fuller unit root test. However, I am dealing with very small numbers (differences are often zero or very close to zero) so I get a terrible fit when I try to do multiple linear regression with first differences. If I do OLS with the original data, I have a high R^2 value but a very low Durbin-Watson statistic. As a result, I am afraid I'll have a spurious regression problem

To try and account for the autocorrelation, I made a model using a lagged dependent variable alongside several independent variables. My question is, is this a valid model to use if my data is non-stationary at levels? I am not really sure how to proceed with my I(1), autocorrelated data if first differences isn't working out the way I hoped

I would also like to point out that when I do multiple linear regression with independent variables at levels (and no lagged variable), I get a good fit. So I'm not sure if I am worrying about spurious regression when in fact it's not a problem in this case.

Any help is appreciated here!

Comment: Yes you can add lagged variable values in a linear model to try and deal with the autocorrelation and non-stationarity. Check your model residuals with ACF and PACF plots.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I check my residuals and I can say my errors are stationary, do you think it's safe to say the model isn't spurious? I'm thinking I can use that as justification for using non-stationary data

Comment: I don't know if you can claim that.